# Searchable custom tags for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, search, metadata, tagging

I want to tag certain parts of my code with various words, and then find them later.

For example, if I add these tags to a function like this...

```
// #variable #clipboard #select
public void myfunc() {
    // Lots of code...
}
```

...then I want to be able to search for those tags, even in reverse order! For example, I might search for: `clipboard variable`, and it would find the function. Alternatively, I might search for something where one term isn't in the tag list. For example, `select clipboard key`. Although `key` isn't a tag, two of the words match, so Visual Studio would put it at (or near) the top of the search results.

How can I achieve this? It would GREATLY simplify hunting for old pieces of code.

Comment: If it is your own code, you probably know where to look for the snippet even years later. If it is someone elses code, he probably won't use the tags you search for. But I think I have seen something like this in Stash some time ago: https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash Other Git-integrations have equivalent functionality for sure.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your problem, you want to be able to find any block of code with arbitrary keywords? I took a look at all of the Visual Studio 2010 find/replace tools but I don't think that any of them will really be what you're hoping for. My only solution that I think might work for arbitrary ordering of keywords would be if you were to write your commented out code like

```
//clipboard variable select clipboard select variable clipboard select variable clipboard select clipboard variable...
```

Obviously that's a very tedius workaround, but it technically could help if there was some code that you *really* did not want to lose. One thing to remember is that C# is not responsible for keeping code organized and easy to navigate - that's completely up to the programmer.

Instead of trying to use keywords to find important methods within a gigantic block of text, I suggest minimizing methods or classes that you're not currently using. If you've finished writing the method/class, you should click the [-] sign to the left of the start of the method/class so that it doesn't take up so much space. If you minimize your code properly, things shouldn't be nearly as hard to find.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Upvote for checking out all the existing programs. Two problems with minimizing methods: 1: They auto-expand when you find a term that you search for, so it undoes all your work..... 2: If I want to go back months or years later, the required code could be in one of those 'hidden' methods.

Comment: Okay, just thought it might be handy. Have you tried looking for programs outside the immediate Visual Studio 2010 software, maybe extensions offered on other websites? Somebody may have already solved this problem with an extension program for C#.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the `MetadataType` attribute in your code.[MSDN for metadata type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx#Y1283)

If you want it searchable and easy to manage, the tool of choice is something like [Atlassian fisheye](https://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview). I think sventon (as an alternative to that) is no longer active.